# Setting value at same objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array with objects in it. I want to give id to the objects in the array if the objects have the same values. I wrote a code like below but it doesn't work correctly. my English is not good. I hope I explained my opinion correctly.

here is my current array

```
arr[
{sender: "hashim", message: "i am hashim"},
{sender: "hashim", message: "i am hashim"},
{sender: "tester", message: "i am tester"},
{sender: "tester", message: "i am tester"},
...
]
```

So here is my expected array:

```
arr[
{sender: "hashim", message: "i am hashim",id:5},
{sender: "hashim", message: "i am hashim",id: 5},
{sender: "tester", message: "i am tester",id: 5},
{sender: "tester", message: "i am tester",id : 5},
...
]
```

here is my function :

```
    let duplicates = [];

  const dublFinder = (arr) => {
    arr.findIndex(function (item, index) {
      if (item.sender === item.sender) {
        item.id = index;
        duplicates.push(item)
    };
    });
  };

  dublFinder(roomMessages);
```

Comment: It is not so clear what exactly do you want. Please add  [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and expected result?

Comment: Sorry for question. Here is my  my object in array : {sender: "hashim", message: "i am hashim"}

Comment: Add your array and expected result in question itself.

Comment: So if the names are the same i want to change this to :  {sender: "hashim", message: "i am hashim", id: 4}

Comment: Please add your data i.e. array and expected result as a code not a english sentence in the **question itself**

Comment: That's not a valid array. We can't reproduce your code and work on the code that you have provided. You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that everyone can understand it properly

Comment: I'm not able to see that you have edited the question

Comment: ok, the array is fine now just tell me how you want to add `id` in the final result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code which updates assigns `id` in sequence and assigns same `id` if it is a duplicate -

```js
var arr = [{
    sender: "hashim",
    message: "i am hashim"
  },
  {
    sender: "hashim",
    message: "i am hashim"
  },
  {
    sender: "tester",
    message: "i am tester"
  },
  {
    sender: "tester",
    message: "i am tester"
  }
];

const modifiedArr = [];
let iterator = 1;
for (const item of arr) {
  const existingItem = modifiedArr.find(f => f.sender == item.sender);
  if (existingItem) {
    item.id = existingItem.id;
  } else {
    item.id = iterator++;
  }
  modifiedArr.push(item);
}
console.log(modifiedArr);
```

Comment: This answer is not so optimized. It is `O(n * 2)`. It can easily be accomplished in `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this result in `O(n)` using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
var arr = [
  {
    sender: "hashim",
    message: "i am hashim",
  },
  {
    sender: "hashim",
    message: "i am hashim",
  },
  {
    sender: "tester",
    message: "i am tester",
  },
  {
    sender: "tester",
    message: "i am tester",
  },
];

const dict = new Map();

const result = arr.map((obj) => {
  dict.get(obj.sender) ?? dict.set(obj.sender, ++dict.size);
  return { ...obj, id: dict.get(obj.sender) };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for answers. So, can you explain that code logic? i never saw "??" operator in javascript

Comment: It is [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Comment: The nullish coalescing operator (??) is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.